# Extract from text the first and 6th column if there is a 6th column

Tags: regex, grep, cut

I have data in following format and I want to extract the first column and the column 6, if there is a column six:

```
ID1        Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;
ID2        Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;Eubacteriaceae;Eubacterium;Eubacterium hallii;
ID3        Bacteria;Firmicutes;
ID4        Bacteria;Firmicutes;
ID5        Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;
ID6        Bacteria;
ID7        Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;Ruminococcaceae;Faecalibacterium;
ID8        Bacteria;Firmicutes;Clostridia;Clostridiales;Ruminococcaceae;Faecalibacterium;Faecalibacterium prausnitzii;
```

The output should be:

```
ID2 Eubacterium
ID7 Faecalibacterium
ID8 Faecalibacterium
```

I try to solve the problem by split by ";" and grep the 6th column `cut -d ";" -f 6` but think you will have a better solution. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use awk:

```
awk -F\; 'NF>=6{print substr ($1, 0, 4), $6}' file
```

If there are 6 or more fields, then it extracts fields 1 and 6 based on delimiter `;`. and then extracts first 3 chars from field 1.

Sample output:

```
$ awk -F\; 'NF>=6{print substr ($1, 0, 4), $6}' file
ID2 Eubacterium
ID7 Faecalibacterium
ID8 Faecalibacterium
```

Comment: Nice answer. I guess that if you don't specify that the separator is ; awk would assume that there are only two columns separated by whitespace, and it would be much harder to extract the fields.

Comment: Ugh. Do people still use awk?

Comment: @pguardiario yes, they do ;-)

Comment: Yeah, Let me rant for a bit on why this is a bad answer. Poster tags a question with regex, grep and cut. This is clearly a problem that can be solved with those utilities. By answering with awk you've essentially given him a fish that he can't catch himself instead of teaching him how to catch a fish if you'll excuse the metaphor. It's about as far against the spirit of SO as you can get IMNSHO.

Comment: @pguardiario While this can be done with grep/cut/regex, I don't think OP cares about the tool. If he edits the post and adds awk then this will become good answer to you? I also request to you look at *all* the answers under the tags grep/cut/awk/regex/sed etc to see how they teach to *fish*. Most of these are simple tools that doesn't need any teaching and all it takes is to read the man pages and try some samples. You seem to intent on downvoting and needed a stupid reason for that. I'll forever cherish your downvote.

Comment: I disagree. Awk is an obscure utility with an arcane syntax. Nobody who doesn't already know it will ever bother to learn it because it's simply a dinosaur. If OP asked for an awk solution obviously that's a different matter, forcing awk on unwitting posters strikes me as especially cruel though.

Comment: @pguardiario There are people out there who have such an opinion (obsure/bad/arcane etc) on *every* language. That doesn't make them correct nor does it stop people from using those languages. The whole thing `Awk is an obscure utility with an arcane syntax. Nobody who doesn't already know it will ever bother to learn it because it's simply a dinosaur` is entirely your opinion and the fact that you sound like an authoritarian doesn't make it any truer. Your only point of contetion is the tag. The fact that OP accepted my answer shows OP doesn't mind an awk solution.

Comment: Well I did say it was a rant. Answering a non-awk question with awk is bad news, obviously that's just my opinion but I'm sticking with it.

Comment: @pguardiario I have no problem someone ranting something on The Internet. I *do* have a problem when someone says my answer is bad because I used an arcane and then downvotes my answer saying wrong tag for which the OP had no problem and happily accepted it.

Comment: +1 Upvoting mostly just to demonstrate vehement disagreement with @pguardiano. Awk is "obscure" because it's "specialized". The fact that it's specialized for just this sort of problem makes it much more elegant and succinct than the corresponding solution in whatever general-purpose *langue du jour* you deem to be the least obscure, and a good incentive to learn another good tool if you find yourself facing this kind of problem repeatedly.

Comment: awk works well for me, next time I try to improve my tags. Sorry for the unclear question.

Comment: @Blue Moon, Fair enough but if OP's acceptance were a good enough way to judge answers there would be no need for downvotes. Downvotes exist for a reason and I'm sorry if you can't understand that.

Comment: @pguardiario Downvoting in itself is not a problem. Don't just downvote because you don't like the language/your opinion or rant on something. Re tag: This is not like giving a Java answer to a C++ question. You may want to look up all the unix tool chain tags such as awk/sed/grep/cut/tr etc etc on SO. 
I hope you understand. FWIW, awk is part of all unix and Linux. POSIX & LSB spec require that. I am just not convinced your downvote is justified. But I have no problem with that.

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think it's appropriate to post awk answers in non-awk questions. I understand that people do it a lot, but I feel it should be discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

Grep for lines with 6 `;`'s:

```
egrep '(.*;){6}' file
```

Cut columns `1,6` with delimeter `;`

```
cut -f1,6 -d';' file
```

remove the `\s.*;` junk (notice I don't use sed, perl is good for regex):

```
perl -pe 's/\s.*;/ /'
```

Altogether now:

```
egrep '(.*;){6}' file | cut -f1,6 -d';' | perl -pe 's/\s.*;/ /'
```

There you go , an answer using grep, cut and regex.

Comment: Well, I use grep, cut, and regex which the poster already knows (I assume) and I'm happy to clarify anything that needs it.

Comment: I am happy to explain anything OP needs as well. In fact, I have already explained how my works. As I said before, you needed a reason to downvote.

Comment: If you end up using Perl anyway, might as well do it all in Perl. `perl -lnaF ';' -e 'next unless $#F > 5; $F[0] =~ s/\t.*/\t/; print $F[0], $F[5]'`

Comment: ... Perl is obscure, though. (-:

Comment: I dislike awk, too. But in this case awk is easier to understand. Anyway, thanks for your explanation.

Comment: Perl is obscure but using it for search/replace is straightforward.